# pymongo MongoClient connection failed due to pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo1:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I have installed 3 node mongodb with replicaset.

Docker images are started to bind all ip address.

`command: mongod --replSet engline-rs --journal --bind_ip_all`

I am able to connect the database using

```
mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin
```

in robo3T or mongodb compass. But with the same uri my python code is not able to connect to the server.

Got below error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
mongo1:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,
mongo3:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,
mongo2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, 
Timeout: 30s, 
Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6268ec793318f4b4ce36f100, 
topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongo1', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=AutoReconnect('mongo1:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, 
<ServerDescription ('mongo2', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=AutoReconnect('mongo2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, 
<ServerDescription ('mongo3', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=AutoReconnect('mongo3:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>]>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i have the same problem..did u solve it?